# Using pychef to upload an environment file by using the Chef REST API, but getting an error

Tags: python, chef-infra, pychef

I am using [pychef](https://github.com/coderanger/pychef) to run commands on the Chef server, largely with success. Pychef does not currently have cookbook support (uploading, downloading, etc), but it is exposed in the Chef Server REST API and pychef has functions that let you easily hit the chef api (putting together the auth credential headers and whatnot for you).

So I have an environment on the server called let's say `my_environment`, and I'm trying to update a cookbook version in the environment file to say `"some_cookbook": "= 1.2.3"`, so my entire environment file will look like:

```
    {
        "json_class": "Chef::Environment", 
        "chef_type": "environment", 
        "cookbook_versions": {
            "some_cookbook": "= 1.2.3"
        }, 
        "description": "example environment file", 
        "name": "my_environment"
    }
```

So, I create the chef api object like:

```
    chef_api = chef.ChefAPI(BASE_CHEF_URL + "/" + my_organization, chef_key, CHEF_USER)
    # BASE_CHEF_URL is something like https://my.chef.server/organizations
```

The ChefApi class has the `request()` function on it, and I use it thus:

```
    chef_api.request("PUT", "/environments/my_environment", data=json.dumps(environment_file_dict))
    # environment_file_dict is the dictionary shown above.
```

However, I get an error message back saying: `chef.exceptions.ChefServerError: The '_default' environment cannot be modified.`.

This is confusing, as given my endpoint I really don't expect this to attempt to change the `_default` environment. I have tried looking through Chef and Knife code to find the source of the problem to no avail and the docs on the chef website also have not seemed to shed any light. What is also strange is I can do the same thing except with a `"GET"` and pull down my environment file perfectly fine. Any ideas?

Comment: You have not indicated what version of Chef server you're using. Assuming Chef 12 the documentation suggests you're using the wrong REST URL endpoint. See: https://docs.chef.io/api_chef_server.html#id44

Comment: I believe we're using chef 11. But, I think I see the confusion. The ChefAPI object has the beginning of the endpoint already and just appends the endpoint passed in. So it has `https://my.chef.server/organizations/my_org` and appends to make the full URL: `https://my.chef.server/organizations/my_org/environments/my_environment`, which I believe is the correct endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I realize I was wrong about pychef and my question. This is a case of not reading the documentation enough. While it is true that pychef does not upload/download cookbooks, it *does* easily deal with chef **Environments**: https://pychef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#environments. What I did was I created a chef api in the same way as above:

```
    chef_api = chef.ChefAPI(BASE_CHEF_URL + "/" + my_organization, chef_key, CHEF_USER)
```

Then I use the Environment object to update an existing environment:

```
    import chef  # This is the pychef module
    env_obj = chef.Environment("my_environment", api=chef_api)
    # env_obj now has attributes corresponding to the environment json that 
    # you can upload and download with knife or view on the chef server
    env_obj.cookbook_versions["some_cookbook"] = "= 3.2.1"
    env_obj.save() # This will save the object to the chef server
```

I, however, still have no explanation for the error "The '_default' environment cannot be modified".